# R: mapply versus for loop: identical performance

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, intersect, mapply

I am trying to get the most optimized performance for a piece of code, but I am getting almost identical performance between mapply and for loops. Why is that? Would plyr or data.table be faster? Or is there a more efficient way to write my function?

The first chunk of code creates a list of 1000 lists, each nested list containing 1-10 random letters.

```
testlist<-list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  testlist[i]<-list(paste(sample(c(letters),sample(1:10, 1))))}
```

The script that I am trying to optimize is one that counts the number of intersections across all possible combinations (1,000,000) of my nested lists. Below illustrates the mapply syntax I used for this.

```
#Function for mapply
  intersectfunction<-function(x,y){
    length(intersect(x,y))
  }
#mapply syntax
  T1<-Sys.time()
  Intersects<-mapply(x=rep(testlist,length(testlist)),intersectfunction,y=rep(testlist,each=length(testlist)))
  mapplytime<-Sys.time()-T1
```

Below illustrates a nested for loop syntax that produces essentially identical output.

```
T1<-Sys.time()
Intersects<-vector(length=length(testlist)^2)
for(i in 1:length(testlist)){
 for(j in 1:length(testlist)){
   Intersects[j+((i-1)*length(testlist))]<-length(intersect(testlist[[i]],testlist[[j]]))
 }
}
forlooptime<-Sys.time()-T1
```

The weird thing is that each syntax takes almost the same amount of time, even though it seems like mapply should be more efficient. This suggests to me that I am either doing something wrong with mapply, or that mapply is not the right tool for accomplishing my goal.

```
> mapplytime
Time difference of 20.97202 secs
> forlooptime
Time difference of 23.29733 secs
```

Comment: Why do you think `mapply` will be much more efficient? They both have to do essentially the same processing. They myth that "loops are slow" in R is not true. The problem is usually memory allocation and you took care of that by pre-allocating the output.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I think we want to know if the code can be more efficient, not the "why" the performance is the same for `forloop` and `mapply`. If that is the case, then why every combo, maybe `combn(1:1000, 2)` ? Also, there is a function `lengths()`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. MrFlick - I do not often use mapply, but I have had a great deal of luck speeding up my scripts with sapply instead of for-loops (sometimes dramatically). I could give examples if you are skeptical. But maybe I misunderstand how mapply works. zx8754 - Interesting suggestions. I will see if they help.

Comment: @BrianA Examples where `sapply()` is faster than a for loop even after proper memory initialization would be interesting to see. I've asked others for such examples and they have failed to deliver.

Comment: @MrFlick I just looked through some of my old code. It looks like you're right - I'm not seeing much of a difference between sapply and for loops after assigning proper memory allocation. I'm not sure why I thought should be a difference... Sorry about that.